# twitter sharing using sharekit crashing in ios 5

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

Hi I'm trying to a share images using sharekit on twitter,from app. I have added a twitter icon and when clicked I call this function

```
 -(void)shareTwitter
{
    SHKItem *itemshare = [SHKItem image:imgView.image title:projectname];
    [SHK setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
    [SHKTwitter shareItem:itemshare];
}
```

after this function is executed the app crashes saying **exec_bad_access** in sharekit code.
I have added the piece of line below where it occurs.

```
iOS5twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) ;
```

I tried to reproduce the same issue with the demoapp provided by sharekit.The app runs fine and even posts image.

The crash appears before login authentication. can someone  guide me thru this and help me fix this issue 
thanks